# Access, Passing A single value from a continous form to another form

Tags: ms-access-2010

So I've seen this question come up quite a bit in the search feed but I have not seen one come up for a continuous form. What I'm trying to accomplish is passing a text field value (Part_Number) from a sub form, which is a continuous form, onto another form called Part Profile and populate a text field. Right now everything is set up by a button on the continuous form and once clicked it will open up the part profile then upon load of the new form it will reference the openargs on the button.

I would post the code I have in place but I'm still learning the ropes and have not used openargs before.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the form, read its property *OpenArgs*. It will hold the value you passed (Part_Number). If nothing is passed, *OpenArgs* is *Null*.

Then use that value as you like - to filter the form or go to a record.